# Submitting app to iTunes connect in a team

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I created a bundle ID in the team's section, but it is not showing up in iTunes connect. Can I not do any team-related actions in iTunes connect? Does the team account need to create the app in iTunes connect?

EDIT: I just found that the team's account needs to add me to their iTunes connect "Users and Roles". Is this the reason for my issue?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, you need to be either Technical or Admin role to be able to create a App record.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/CreatingiTunesConnectRecord.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13)

If you are not either, you could have the admin reassign your role to technical.

Comment: My role in the team is Admin

Comment: Is the plus sign missing completely?  iTunes Connect can be buggy.

Comment: The plus sign is there and works fine. When I add an iOS app, the bundle ID for my team is not in the list

Comment: Definitely seems that the problem is you haven't been added to Users and Roles as per your edit.

Comment: I just asked the team leader to add me to their Users and Roles, but they can't because "The email address you entered already belongs to an iTune Connect account"